# PHP: Check if email already exists when running this code

Tags: php

I have built a very simple PHP form that allows a user to send an application using the following PHP code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $host = '###';
        $username = '###';
        $pass = '###';

        mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
        mysql_select_db("###");

        $status    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
        $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
        $email     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $url       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO creathive_applications 
                  VALUES (NULL,'$status','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$url')";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().". Query: ".$query);
    }
```

What I want to do is make sure that the same person doesn't apply TWICE so if the email address already exists in the database then it will show a message on the form saying "sorry looks like you've already applied".

Here is the HTML form, and I have added the message inside the fieldset, so need to do a) show this message if the email exits or show success message and then b) add #membership form to the url to make the view jump to form on the page so that the user will see the messages. Can any help with this? THANKS

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                            <fieldset id="membershipform">
                    <div id="error"><p>sorry email in use</p></div>
<div id="success"><p>Thanks your application has been sent</p></div>
                                <ul class="clearfix">
                                    <li id="li-status">
                                        <span>I am a:</span>
                                        <menu>
                                            <li><label for="student"><input type="radio" name="status" id="student" checked="checked" value="Graduate" /> Graduate</label></li>
                                            <li><label for="student2"><input type="radio" name="status" id="student2" value="Undergraduate" /> Undergraduate</label></li>
                                        </menu>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-firstname">
                                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label> <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" title="First Name" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-lastname">
                                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label> <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" title="Last Name" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-email">
                                        <label for="email">Email address</label> <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="email" title="Email address" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-url">
                                        <label for="url">URL</label> <input name="url" type="text" placeholder="URL of something you've made" id="url" title="URL of something you've made" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-buttons">
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Application &#9658;" title="Send Application" />
                                    </li>
                                </ui>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a select query before insert to validate there aren't any entries for the email already:

```
select from creathive_applications where email = $email
```

If any results come back, then display your message instead of inserting the record.  You can add javascript onload code to move form to #membershipform if the email already existed.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? Like if an email exists then show the message on the form and if not then run the Insert. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron: Use `mysql_query` to get data. Check if any results came back.  If so, display a message.  If not, run your insert query.  I'm not going to put it all together, because I would be looking up php methods, testing and debugging code on my computer to figure it all out, which is something you should be doing instead.

Comment: Come back with specific questions after you've tried your best to get it working.

Comment: See @Matteo's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can alter table so that email id is primary so it will be  unique.
2. You can check with another query

   select from   creathive_applications where emai='$email'

Answer (score 0):

simple , you must check it agains your database .

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $host = '###';
    $username = '###';
    $pass = '###';

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
    mysql_select_db("###");

    $status    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $email     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $url       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);

    $query_check = "SELECT COUNT(*) as existents FROM creathive_applications .... emailfiel = 'email_entered'";
    switch($query_check['existents']){
        case 0:
            //do the insert operation
            $query = "INSERT INTO creathive_applications VALUES (NULL,'$status','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$url')";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().". Query: ".$query);
        break;
            default:
            echo "no no";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$email` exists in your DB and if it does set `$error = 1`. Then if `$error = 1`, print the message.

```
$emailchk  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM creathive_applications WHERE email = '$email'");
if(mysql_num_rows($emailchk) > 0) {  
    $error = 1;  
}

if isset($error) {  
    echo '<div id="error"><p>sorry email in use</p></div>';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

**PHP Code:**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $host = '###';
    $username = '###';
    $pass = '###';
    $emailerror = null;

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
    mysql_select_db("###");

    $status    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $email     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $url       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);

    $emailchk  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM creathive_applications WHERE email = '$email'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($emailchk) == 0) {  
        $query = "INSERT INTO creathive_applications VALUES (NULL,'$status','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$url')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().". Query: ".$query);
    }else{
        $emailerror = '<span style="color:rgb(255,0,0)">Email already taken</span>';
    }
}
```

**HTML *(Must be in the same file)*:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
                            <fieldset id="membershipform">
                    <div id="error"><p>sorry email in use</p></div>
<div id="success"><p>Thanks your application has been sent</p></div>
                                <ul class="clearfix">
                                    <li id="li-status">
                                        <span>I am a:</span>
                                        <menu>
                                            <li><label for="student"><input type="radio" name="status" id="student" checked="checked" value="Graduate" /> Graduate</label></li>
                                            <li><label for="student2"><input type="radio" name="status" id="student2" value="Undergraduate" /> Undergraduate</label></li>
                                        </menu>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-firstname">
                                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label> <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" title="First Name" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-lastname">
                                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label> <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" title="Last Name" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-email">
                                        <label for="email">Email address</label> <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="email" title="Email address" /> <?php echo $emailerror;?>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-url">
                                        <label for="url">URL</label> <input name="url" type="text" placeholder="URL of something you've made" id="url" title="URL of something you've made" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="li-buttons">
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Application &#9658;" title="Send Application" />
                                    </li>
                                </ui>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```